# Vulnerability Scan Authorization for Google Compute

Tags: google-compute-engine

What is the official and required process to perform our own independent vulnerability scans against virtual machines in the Google Compute Engine? These will be Penetration tests (our own) that will scan the public IP for open ports and report results back to us.

Microsoft Azure requires authorization and so does Amazon. Does Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Google does not need to be notified before you run a security scan on your Google Compute Engine projects. You will have to abide by Google Cloud Platform [Acceptable Use Policy](https://cloud.google.com/terms/aup) and the [Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/terms/).

Please also be aware of Google's [Vulnerability Rewards Program Rules](http://www.google.com/about/appsecurity/reward-program/).

Answer (score 0):

By default all incoming traffic from an outside network is blocked. Each customer has the responsibility to create the appropriate rules to allow access to the GCE instances as he considers appropriate:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#firewalls

If you sign up for a trial you can perform that test over your own project. Overall security configuration is up to the owner of the project and does not reside on Google.

In regards to internal infrastructure Google has its own security teams working 24x 7 to assure it keeps on the vanguard in the best security practices.  http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.ca/

Comment: Thanks Carlos. Understood that we control our own firewall settings and port forwarding. I am pretty sure that Google's overall security is top notch as per their SOC 2 reports and other documentation. We, however have customers that require independent security audits, no matter where the virtual machine resides, be that Microsoft Azure, Amazon EC2, or Google Compute. To do this we need to scan the public IP address setup for the VM in the Compute Engine. Question is: do we need authorization from Google to do that and how do we get that authorization? MS and Amazon require this.